# In c how can I detect if any bit of a byte equal 0

Tags: c, bit

I was able to check for 1's using (x && 0xf), but I have no idea how to detect 0's.

```
check_zeros(int y){


} //return 1 if 0 is found
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `(x && 0xf)` was doing for you, did you perhaps mean `(x & 0xff)`?

Comment: yeah it should be (x & 0xff) == x, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
int check_zeros(int y) {
    return (y & 0xff) != 0xff;
}
```

The `0xff` represents a byte with all bits set to 1.

Comment: I think you forgot to mask out only the lowest byte.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thanks, totally missed the "byte" part. Fixed.

Comment: wouldn't (y & 0x01) != 0x01 work too, in a 32bit environment?

Comment: 0x01 == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

Answer (score 2):

Supposing it's an 8-bit value (from 0 to 0xFF):

```
int check_zeros(int y) {
    return y < 0xFF;
    // alternatively: return y != 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: @pst That's exactly what I meant with `Supposing it's an 8-bit value (from 0 to 0xFF)`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have your function declared, y is not a byte, it's an integer. So I assume you want to find out if ANY bit in y is zero.

```
int check_zeros(int y)
{
    return ((~y) != 0);
}
```

Comment: The ~ (tilda) character is bitwise NOT. Inverts all the bits.  So (int)~0 is logically an integer with all bits set (without having to know what sizeof(int) is on that platform).  I've updated my answer such that the tilda is now applied to y and compared to zero. That just looks cleaner.